# How do I find required sample size for my survey given the data I have from my pilot survey?

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, survey, bernoulli-distribution, survey-sampling

I have a data set which has a boolean variable (the question being 'Have you been the recipient of a blood transfusion?') it has either yes or no as the output.

I currently have 118 replies to this question (about .0518 of the respondents have said yes) and want to find out how many more people I should ask this question before I have a 95% confidence interval on the true proportion of people in the whole population.

I have used the formula (3) from the paper [Modern Methods in the Sampling of Human by JEROME CORNFIELD](https://ajph.aphapublications.org/doi/pdf/10.2105/AJPH.41.6.654) but I'm not fully sure if it's correct.

I have also used the formula (Z_(α/2)*std.dev)/(α*μ) and got smaller value for sample size as compared to the previous formula.

I would really thankful is someone could walk me through how I should go about doing this. Thanks you so much in advance!

Comment: You can already construct a 95% confidence interval from this information.  Is it adequate for your needs?

Comment: @whuber I'm sorry I don't fully understand. I need know how to find the required number of data points to collect in order have a 95% CI on the answer to the question.

Comment: I will repeat: *you can compute a CI from the data you have.*  Do so and see whether it is adequate for the decisions you plan to make.  (I am reluctant to do the computation because the information you provide is not mathematically consistent: 0.0518 of 118 replies is 6.11 replies, whereas 6 replies would be 0.0508 of the total, leading me to suspect some of the information you report is wrong. But, as an example, if the correct value is 6 yeses out of 118 replies, then the Clopper-Pearson 95% confidence interval goes from 0.019 to 0.107.)

Comment: Please [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=binomial+%22confidence+interval%22+score%3A2).

Comment: @whuber you're right on the .0508 number, my apologies! I'm guessing now using the 95% confidence interval range I compute the value of n again to get the required number of responses for my final survey?

Comment: Nikhil, you misunderstand what a CI is, it is the range of values or percentages around the result you got that could also have been obtained from the same sample with 95% probablilty, the larger the sample, the narrower the range would be.